# Install NPM package while running app

Tags: node.js, npm

Can I force Node.JS install `npm`-package when executing `require('package')`
instead of triggering error?

It will be more convenient than running `npm i package` for every package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set Node.js to do this (since Node doesn't actually know about `npm`).

I wouldn't recommend doing anything like this; if you mistyped a package name, you would download the wrong package, possibly running malicious code on your computer.

Remember, anyone can publish an npm package, and packages can run any command (including `rm -rf`) during the installation process.

---

***Follow the below at your own risk:***

You can get something like the behavior you're describing with https://github.com/siddharthkp/auto-install.

```
npm install -g auto-install
cd project-name/
auto-install
```

I would recommend using the `--secure` option for `auto-install`. That will only install popular modules (> 10k downloads in the last month). This will eliminate some of the risk of typos, however, if you're using an uncommon package, it won't be installed automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Dependency packages should be managed through package.json file.
It's because you can easily manage the version of packages required by you application. I don't think it's a good practice to install dependency at runtime.

Reference: [Using a package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json)

Answer (score 1):

Theorically, you could modify `require` to start a cmd and intall the package if not found. It will be hard, non standard and horrendous.

What you can do instead, is use `package.json`, which you can create automatically with `npm init`.

It will ask for the name of the package and some other question, then when you know which package you need, you can

```
npm install --save package
```

which will automatically add the package in `package.json`.

With `package.json` set, you can simply run

```
npm install
```

and it will automatically install every package declared in `package.json`.

It will have other nice pro, like allowing you to ensure which version of the package will be installed (preventing breaking change in the dependency), knowing what your dependencies are without navigating your code, and preparing your code to be pushed in `npm`.